# Fail to add a linear trend line on a barplot in R

Tags: r, plot, trendline

I have created a barplot using `barplot` and then I want to show the linear trend. I use `abline` but the linear trend line does not show in the figure. I wonder what the problem is. Thanks.

```
set.seed(100)
Mydata=rnorm(65)
Year=1950:2014
barplot(Mydata)
fit=lm(Mydata~Year)
abline(fit)
```

[image]

As @G5W points out, `fit=lm(Mydata~I(Year-1950))`. But the new problem is that the trend line is too "long". As shown in the second figure, the trend line goes beyond the barplot. Is there any advice?

[image]

Comment: Instead of `barplot`, try `plot(Year, Mydata, type = 'h')`

Comment: Or,  if you want to stay with the barplot,  change your lm statement to be `fit=lm(Mydata~I(Year-1950))`.   The problem is the x-coordinates of the barplot are not the year numbers,

Comment: @G5W It shows the linear trend line, but the intercept and slope are not the same as that obtained from using `lm(Mydata~Year)'. This may be a problem. Could you explain more about your code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: the problem is that the x-coordinates for the barplot are _not_ the years.  Instead, it shifts things so that the value for 1950 appears at x=0.  You can see this by typing `abline(v=0, col="red")`. I just shifted the years so that things would line up. If you want to report the trend line,  use your original, but mine works with the barplot.

Comment: @G5W Pleae see my updated post for a new question using `fit=lm(Mydata~I(Year-1950))`. Thanks.

Comment: Ugh! try `abline(v=64, col="red")`  and you will see that the box widths are not 1 unit each. that makes the two actual answers more attractive than my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)    

df <- data.frame(Mydata, Year)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Mydata)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, ggplot is a very usefull tool. If I want to use red and green color for data >=0 and data<0, respectively, how can I do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Mydata)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = as.factor(Mydata >= 0))) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "darkgreen")) +
  guides(fill = FALSE)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @bouncyball's comment, use a higher value of line width (`lwd`) to resemble `barplot` if you want.

```
plot(Year, Mydata, type = 'h',lwd=5,col = "grey")
abline(fit, lty =2)
```

**EDIT**

First copy this function

```
barplot2 <- function(x, y, lty = 1, lwd = 1, col = "grey", border = "black"){
w = ((max(x) - min(x))/length(x)) * 0.75
plot(x, y, type = 'p', pch = NA, yaxt = "n", xaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
for (i in 1:length(x)){
x1  = x[i] - w/2
x2 = x[i] + w/2
y1 = 0
y2 = y[i]
polygon(x = c(x1,x2,x2,x1), y = c(y1,y1,y2,y2), lty = lty, lwd = lwd, col = col, border = border)
}
}
```

Then make the barplot

```
barplot2(Year,Mydata)
```

Then add the `ablineclip` from `plotrix` library

```
ablineclip(fit, x1 = min(Year), x2 = max(Year), y1 = min(Mydata), y2 = max(Mydata))
```

[image]

Comment: In this way, the plot is not a bar even you increase the line width.

Comment: Thank you for your help.